# Extraer coordenadas de google maps desde nombre de una locacion

Tags: codeigniter-4, google-maps-v3

He buscado la solución y la tengo a casi a medias, expongo la situción.

Estoy actualizando un sistema que en las versiones anteriores del API de google maps podian extraer fácilmente la longitud y latitud de un hotel para determinar el costo del viaje.

Ahora con el cambio de framework y la versión del API, estoy atorado y considero que puede ser algo relativamente sencillo pero no le encuentro.

YA logre traer la información del API, ya logre obtener la información que necesito pero cuando la quiero sacar de la función es donde me quedo atorado.

El input es le nombre del hotel.

```
function getCoordenadas(input){

  $.ajax({
    method:'GET',
    url:'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json',
    data:{address:input,
          key:"API_KEY"
    },
    success: (json) => {
     resultado =json.results[0].geometry.location;

     data = {
      'latitud' : resultado.lat,
      'longitud' : resultado.lng
     };
      return data;
    },
    error: function(){
      console.log('fallo');
    }
  });
```

}

El tema es el valor que me regresa es *undefined*, ya sea que lo regrese como Array o como Json algo esta haciendo mal.

Comment: donde te esta regresando ese "undefined" ? en el metodo error o en el metodo success? si es este ultimo, haz un alert del valor de json para ver que contiene. Puede ser que ahora venga con otro formato y no te valga el json.results[0] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En este minuto tu función no retorna:

```
function getCoordenadas(input){
  $.ajax({
         // todo lo demás
  })
}
```

Eso es como si pusieras

```
function getCoordenadas(input){
   console.log('hola')
}
```

Como primera medida tendrás que retornar algo desde la función.

```
function getCoordenadas(input){
     return $.ajax({...})
}
```

Pero cómo... si ahí sale claramente `return data`? Cierto, pero estamos tratando con una función asíncrona. Lo que salga de ella nunca será un par de coordenadas, dado que no estamos tomando en cuenta la demora del request en ir hasta google, la demora del geocoder para resolver la query o la demora de la respuesta en viajar de regreso.

Por lo mismo, lo que puedes obtener de ahí es, de buenas a primeras, una promesa. (Que se resolverá con un par de coordenadas)

```
getCoordenadas(input).then(latLng=>console.log(latLng))
```

o bien

```
let latLng = await  getCoordenadas(input)
```

Con la salvedad que la segunda sintaxis no podrás usarlo desde el espacio global en la mayoría de los browsers y runtimes de javascript (siendo 5 de julio de 2022) sino que todo deberá ocurrir dentro de una "función envoltorio".  Nada tan terrible, sino algo como:

```
 async function initMap() {
    let input = document.querySelector('#direccion').value,
    latLng=await getCoordenadas(input)
    console.log(latLng)
 }
 document.addEventListener('domContentLoaded',()=>initMap());
```

Ya que tenemos ese extremo de la ecuación solucionado, veamos el otro extremo. Si retornas desde la función

```
function getCoordenadas(input){
     return $.ajax({...})
}
```

Salvo en caso que estés usando una versión de hace 7 años, eso devuelve una promesa. Para versiones más antiguas, sírvase reemplazar por:

```
function getCoordenadas(input){
     return Promise.resolve($.ajax({...}))
}
```

Esto se debe a que en la antigüedad jQuery intentó sacar adelante su propia implementación de promesas antes de finalmente  adherir al estándar Promise/A+.

Paso siguiente: la sintaxis de jQuery permite realizar llamadas ajax con el estilo callback. Pero lo que estás usando en este caso no nos sirve.

```
   return $.get(url, (geo) => {
         return geo;
   })
```

es como poner

```
   return setTimeout(()=>alert('listo'),1000)
```

Esa llamada devuelve de inmediato en respuesta a que el evento asíncrono se añadió al stack, pero no tendrás cómo referenciar el resultado.

Si en cambio lo planteas todo como una cadena de promesas que se resuelve como un caminito de dominó, tampoco necesitas saber cuándo se resuelve: deja que las promesas se entiendan entre sí y tú sólo tendrás que lidiar con la última.

Para obtener una promesa, entonces, lo llamarías como:

```
   return $.ajax({url}).then( geo => {
       return geo
   })
```

---

El resultado final es elegante y fácil de interpretar.

```js
function getCoordenadas(input) {

  return $.ajax({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json',
      data: {
        address: input,
        key: "API_KEY"
      }
    })
    .then(json => {
      return json.results[0].geometry.location;
    })
});

async function initMap() {
  let input = document.querySelector('#direccion').value
  try {
    const {
      latitud,
      longitud
    } = await getCoordenadas(input)
    console.log({
      latitud,
      longitud
    })
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }
}
document.addEventListener('domContentLoaded', () => initMap());
```

Ojo que así como sólo tengo que lidiar con el último eslabón de una cadena de promesas, también me basta con atrapar la excepción en el tope de la cadena. Cualquier excepción que salte de ahí hacia adentro viajará aguas arriba por sí misma.

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciono y ya pude avanzar!